# How to match the values in mongodb array collection with array of ids?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I had list of ids in array

```
Employees array

let employeeIds= [
    ObjectId("5b0d4c5ec47e6223a08af5fd"),
    ObjectId("5b1625f762368179e1e4549c"),
    ObjectId("5b3a15979a68763230202dfd"),
    ObjectId("5b3b0ea9074f944699f1bcfc"),
    ObjectId("5b45eb1214e42414cc9a2191"),
    ObjectId("5b83e3fc6fcad70850159ae2"),
    ObjectId("5bdc5a8ab8d82616a54b5667"),
    ObjectId("5bdc5b43d9c22617406f5b4d"),
    ObjectId("5bdd3a9da9ad6b138b503d7d"),
    ObjectId("5bf7e3840c414b4a1612da36"),
    ObjectId("5c18d04256573a536a201599"),
    ObjectId("5c18d05b56573a536a2015a2"),
    ObjectId("5ba8c52a5e0e986f16102c6f"),
    ObjectId("5ba34247decd71414691021d"),
    ObjectId("5bdd3d0ccf9d1417166e47ec")
]
```

In my mongodb stores collection, there are list of employees in array

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5b0d3fa6b426ea12ec0f6e5a"),
    "name" : "xxxx",
    "email" : "xxx@yyy.com",
    "telephone" : "24301212",
    "mobile" : "+91********",
    "employees" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b0d4c5ec47e6223a08af5fd"), 
        ObjectId("5b45eb1214e42414cc9a2191"), 
        ObjectId("5b3b0ea9074f944699f1bcfc"), 
        ObjectId("5b1625f762368179e1e4549c"), 
        ObjectId("5b83e3fc6fcad70850159ae2"), 
        ObjectId("5bdc5a8ab8d82616a54b5667"), 
        ObjectId("5bdc5b43d9c22617406f5b4d"), 
        ObjectId("5bdd3a9da9ad6b138b503d7d"), 
        ObjectId("5b3a15979a68763230202dfd"), 
        ObjectId("5bf7e3840c414b4a1612da36"), 
        ObjectId("5c18d04256573a536a201599"), 
        ObjectId("5c18d05b56573a536a2015a2")
    ],
}
```

I need to compare employees array in my store employees collection with mongodb query. I tried using `find()` the store & using lodash to took the employees who are all match in this store collections. How can I do with in this query? Can you please suggest any idea?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly: Do you want to fetch all documents, which hold an array of employees which holds at least one of the ids referenced in employeeIds, or do you only want documents, where ALL of the ids in the employees array match ALL of the ids in employeeIds?

Comment: Match the employeeIds and store.employees then return who are all in the stores.

Answer (score 1):

This will return all stores, where at least one of the employees is employed at.

```
store.find({
 employees :  {
  $elemMatch: 
   { 
    $in : [ ObjectId("5ba8c52a5e0e986f16102c6f"), ObjectId("5ba34247decd71414691021d")]
   }
 }
})
```